# Compiler has trouble finding Python.h

Tags: compiling, python-2.7, g++

I keep trying to test-compile a simple "hello world" with the gnu compiler on Ubuntu 16.04. The twist is that I am doing THAT because I wanted to make sure the compiler could find the `<Python.h>` - which it couldn't. So it throws me an error in the form of *no such file or directory*. Well, it's definitely there. I located it in 
/usr/include/python2.7 , so I go and include the path:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python2.7
```

Try to compile again. Success. I run the program.
Then I try to recompile the hello.cc. Fails. "Python.h: No such file or directory"
Hmmm... I run `cpp -v` and Get this :

```
Using built-in specs.

COLLECT_GCC=cpp
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

The include path I just added has disappeared...
I installed python-dev(python3-dev etc, etc), and my little program DID compile(actually twice), but rebuilding it fails, and the path goes missing. 
Any thoughts ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see an added `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to appear in the output of `cpp -v` - AFAIK it only shows built-in paths. Why not use `pkg-config --cflags python` to set appropriate flags?

Comment: I did a cpp -v right after one of the successful builds, and it showed the path I had added. Then a little bit later it showed nothing... I'll have to try your option. I'm coming from windows programming so a lot of things go right over my head at first... Thanks.